# Store calculated data in Column of Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

What I'm trying to do is store some data in a specific column that is calculated by using the data from another column.

I currently have a function that returns the number of available licenses for the given `Id` in `JSON`

```
function getAvailableLicenses(id) {
    var url = "/Host/Organization/AvailableLicenses/" + id;
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        return data.AvailableLicenses;
    });
}
```

How do I go about storing this number in a column named "AvailableLicenses"?

Here is my current Grid:

```
$("#OrganizationGrid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: viewModel.get("orgDataSource"),
filterable: {
    extra: false
},
sortable: true,
pageable: true,
columns: [
    { field: "Id", hidden: true },
    { field: "Name", template: "<a href='/Host/Organization/Detail/#:Id#'>#:Name#</a>" },
    { field: "LicenseNumber", title: "Number of Licenses" },
    { field: null, title: "Available Licenses", template: "#= getAvailableLicenses(Id) #" },
    { field: "LicenseExpiration", title: "License Expiration", format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" },
    { field: "State" },
    { field: "Active" }
],
editable: false
});
```

As you can see, I tried to create a null column with a template that calls the function for the given `Id`.
By using Fiddler I can see that the function is indeed being called for all of the rows, but the `AvailableLicenses` column just displays `Undefined` for every row.

Is there something I'm missing here to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the better way to do this is on dataSource `parse()` function

First: you column configuration must change like this:

```
 { field: "AvalableLicenses", title: "Available Licenses" },
```

You alaways can use you template .

And second, inside your `dataSource()` you can add:

```
schema: {
    parse: function(response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
       response[i].AvalableLicenses= null;
       response[i].AvalableLicenses = getAvailableLicenses(response[i].Id)
      }
      return response;
    }
  }
```

EDIT:

If you prefer using you way, I dont see any problem in your configuration, probably your `$.get` is returning undefined, or something you don't expect.
For conviniance I did an example working.

http://jsfiddle.net/jwocf897/

Hope this help

Comment: I debugged it in FireBug and it's definitely returning a number. Not sure why it's saying undefined though. I'll try out the way you suggested though and see how it works :)

Comment: Got it working! I ended up using your way of parsing the data as I believe it's a cleaner way to do it. However, the issue was that I was trying to return a response from my Ajax call without a `success callback` which in return was returning before the call was even finished. This is why it was returning `undefined` every time.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help, and if you need to do more parsing , you can use that method too.